# Newbie - incorrect syntax error near the word where

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
   o.id, o.Name, o.StageName, o.[Type], o.Account__c, o.SalesPerson__c,
   o2.AccountId__c,o2.Sales_Person__c, o2.InvoiceDate__c
FROM customers.dbo.sales as o 
INNER JOIN customers.dbo.account as a on a.Id = o.AccountId 
INNER JOIN
( 
    Select MAX(Id)Id, AccountId 
    FROM customers.dbo.order__c
    WHERE Sales_Person__c <> NULL
) as o1 
INNER JOIN Customers.dbo.Order__c as o2 on o2.Id = o1.Id
WHERE (o.SalesPerson__c = NULL) 
AND (o.[Type] = 'Renewal') 
AND (o.StageName NOT LIKE 'Closed%')
```

Not sure what I did wrong.  I'm getting the following error:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Where'

I'm trying to get the most recent Order for each account.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have invalid syntax all over your query.

Comment: There are no [brackets] in SQL. Maybe you mean one of the Microsoft "products"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is the `<> NULL`  and the `= NULL`, you need to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.  Depending on your RDBMS you also need a `GROUP BY` in your subquery with the `MAX()`:

```
select o.id
    , o.Name
    , o.StageName
    , o.[Type]
    , o.Account__c
    ,o.SalesPerson__c
    , o2.AccountId__c
    , o2.Sales_Person__c
    , o2.InvoiceDate__c
from customers.dbo.sales as o 
Inner Join customers.dbo.account as a 
    on a.Id = o.AccountId 
INNER JOIN
(
    Select MAX(Id)Id, AccountId 
    from customers.dbo.order__c
    where Sales_Person__c IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY AccountId -- depending on the RDBMS you need a GROUP BY
) o1 
INNER JOIN Customers.dbo.Order__c  o2 
    on o2.Id = o1.Id
Where (o.SalesPerson__c IS NULL) 
    and (o.[Type] = 'Renewal') 
    and (o.StageName NOT LIKE 'Closed%')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Inner Join  called o1 doesn't join on anything. I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but I think if you remove the `inner join` for o1, and instead have that as an `exists` in your `where` clause, it might work better. You also have to change your o2 join to join on `o2.AccountId = a.Id`, which I think is what you are trying to do.

```
select o.id
, o.Name
, o.StageName
, o.[Type]
, o.Account__c
, o.SalesPerson__c
, o2.AccountId__c
, o2.Sales_Person__c
, o2.InvoiceDate__c
from customers.dbo.sales as o 
Inner Join customers.dbo.account as a 
    on a.Id = o.AccountId 
INNER JOIN Customers.dbo.Order__c as o2 
    on o2.AccountId = a.Id
Where (o.SalesPerson__c is NULL) 
and (o.[Type] = 'Renewal') 
and (o.StageName NOT LIKE 'Closed%')
and exists(
    Select MAX(Id) as id 
    from customers.dbo.order__c c
    where c.Sales_Person__c is not NULL
    and id = o2.id)
```